# MODIS AQUA Data - Stacking / Mosaic data with python GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

I know how to access and plot subdatasets using gdal and python. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to use the GEO data contained in the HDF4 file so I could look at the same area over many years.

And if possible, can an area be cut out of the data and how?

UPDATE:

To be more specific: I plotted MODIS Data and as you can see below the river moves downwards (rectangular structure top left corner). So over a whole year it's not the same location that i'm observing.

[image]

There's a directory in the subdatasets called Geolocation Fields with Long and Alt directories. So is it possible to access this information or lay it over the data to cut out a specific area?

If we for example take a look at the NASA picture below would it be possible to cut it between 10-15 alt. and -5 to 0 long.

[image]

You can download a sample file by copying the url below:

https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MYD021KM/2009/034/MYD021KM.A2009034.1345.006.2012058160107.hdf

UPDATE:

I ran

```
x0, dx, dxdy, y0, dydx, dy = hdf_file.GetGeoTransform()
```

which gave me the following output:

```
x0:  0.0
dx:  1.0
dxdy:  0.0
y0:  0.0
dydx:  0.0
dy:  1.0
```

As well as

`gdal.Warp(workdir2+"/output.tif",workdir1+"/MYD021KM.A2009002.1345.006.2012058153105.hdf")`

which gave me the following error:

```
ERROR 1: Input file /Volumes/Transcend/Master_Thesis/Data/AQUA_002_1345/MYD021KM.A2009002.1345.006.2012058153105.hdf has no raster bands.
```

**UPDATE 2: **

Here's my code on how I open and read my hdf files:

`all_files` is a list containing file names like:

```
MYD021KM.A2008002.1345.006.2012066153213.hdf
MYD021KM.A2008018.1345.006.2012066183305.hdf
MYD021KM.A2008034.1345.006.2012067035823.hdf
MYD021KM.A2008050.1345.006.2012067084421.hdf
etc .....


for fe in all_files:
    print "\nopening file: ", fe
    try:
        hdf_file = gdal.Open(workdir1 + "/" + fe)
        print "getting subdatasets..."
        subDatasets = hdf_file.GetSubDatasets()
        Emissiv_Bands = gdal.Open(subDatasets[2][0])
        print "getting bands..."
        Bands = Emissiv_Bands.ReadAsArray()
        print "unit conversion ... "

        get_name_tag = re.findall(".A(\d{7}).", all_files[i])[0]
        print "name tag of current file: ", get_name_tag

        # Code for 1 Band:
        L_B_1 = radiance_scales[specific_band] * (Bands[specific_band] - radiance_offsets[specific_band])  # Source: MODIS Level 1B Product User's Guide Page 36 MOD_PR02 V6.1.12 (TERRA)/V6.1.15 (AQUA)
        data_1_band['%s' % get_name_tag] = L_B_1
        L_B_1_mean['%s' % get_name_tag] = L_B_1.mean()

        # Code for many different Bands:
        data_all_bands["%s" % get_name_tag] = []
        for k in Band_nrs[lowest_band:highest_band]: # Bands 8-11
            L_B = radiance_scales[k] * (Bands[k] - radiance_offsets[k])     # List with all bands
            print "Appending mean value of {} for band {} out of {}".format(L_B.mean(), Band_nrs[k], len(Band_nrs))
            data_all_bands['%s' % get_name_tag].append(L_B.mean())          # Mean radiance values

        i=i+1
        print "data added. Adding i+1 = ", i

    except AttributeError:
        print "\n*******************************"
        print "Can't open file {}".format(workdir1 + "/" + fe)
        print "Skipping this file..."
        print "*******************************"
        broken_files.append(workdir1 + "/" + fe)
        i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact data source and desired output etc. it is hard to give you a specific answer. With that said, it appears that you have the native `.hdf` format of MODIS images and wish to do some subsetting to get the images referenced to the same area, then plot etc.

It might help for you to look at `gdal.Warp()` from the `gdal` module. This method is able to take a `.hdf` file and subset a series of images to the same bounding box with the same resolution/number of rows and columns.

You can then analyse and plot these images/compare pixels etc.

I hope that this gives you a good starting point to get started.

`gdal.Warp` docs: https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Warp

More general warp help: https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html

Something like this:

```
import gdal

# Set up the gdal.Warp options such as desired spatial resolution,
# resampling algorithm to use and output format.
# See: https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#WarpOptions
# for other options that can be specified.
warp_options = gdal.WarpOptions(format="GTiff",
                                outputBounds=[min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y],
                                xRes=res,
                                yRes=res,
                                # PROBABLY NEED TO SET t_srs TOO
                                )

# Apply the warp.
# (output_file, input_file, options)
gdal.Warp("/path/to/output_file.tif",
          "/path/to/input_file.hdf",
          options=warp_options)
```

Exact code to write:

```
# Apply the warp.
# (output_file, input_file, options)
gdal.Warp('/path/to/output_file.tif',
          '/path/to/HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MYD021KM.A2009034.1345.006.2012058160107.hdf":MODIS_SWATH_Type_L1B:EV_1KM_RefSB',
          options=warp_options)
```

Comment: thanks for the link! Let me update the question to be more specific

Comment: Judging by your additional explanation, my answer should still apply. Short of writing your code for you I can't do much more than suggest using `gdal.Warp()` with a defined bounding box and this will give you exactly what you need! EDIT: example added to answer

Comment: I tried your suggestion above and got the following error: ERROR 1: `Input file /Volumes/Transcend/Master_Thesis/Data/AQUA_002_1345/MYD021KM.A2009002.1345.006.2012058153105.hdf has no raster bands` . This might be a problem :)

Comment: You have to run the `gdal.Warp()` on the subdataset within the `.hdf` file. I.e using `HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MYD021KM.A2009034.1345.006.2012058160107.hdf":MODIS_SWATH_Type_L1B:EV_1KM_RefSB` as opposed to `MYD021KM.A2009034.1345.006.2012058160107.hdf`

Comment: To add... the `GetGeoTransform()` method did not work because the `.HDF` file is not georeferenced. Converting to `.tif` will get this working.

Comment: Thanks for your input! i appreciate it very much. I'm really struggling with this since i'm fairly new to GDAL and i don't know what's required to get this to work. I'm going to add my code above. Would you be so kind and make the changes as how it should be according to your suggestions above? This way I could see how it should be done correctly